# what are the browser object in javascript? and why need ref of window for using them?

Tags: javascript, object, browser, global-object

browser objects
why we need to use reference of window foe using browser object like location, document

I am trying to understand which are browser object and which are window object? and document is window object or property?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, things like `location` and `document`  are *properties* of `window`. However, as any property of window is implicitly global, it's common to just type `document` instead of `window.document`.